# Access Denied when creating post using managed client object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, client-object-model, social, hashtags

I am using .net client object model for MicroBlogging (Post with hashtags).
I am getting access denied error.

i am using below code

```
   const string serverUrl = "http://usfkl13as133v:9191/en-US/";
                    const string tagName = "#" + "moss2007";

                    // Define the link to a tag that you want to include in the post. If the tag is new, the
                    // server adds it to the tags collection.
                    SocialDataItem tagLink = new SocialDataItem
                    {
                        ItemType = SocialDataItemType.Tag,
                        Text = tagName
                    };

                    // Add the tag to the post's creation data.
                    // Put a placeholder ({0}) where you want the tag to appear in the post text,
                    // and then add the tag to the post's content items.
                    SocialPostCreationData postCreationData = new SocialPostCreationData();
                    postCreationData.ContentText = "I like {0}.";
                    postCreationData.ContentItems = new SocialDataItem[1] { tagLink };

                    try
                    {

                        // Get the context and the SocialFeedManager instance.
                        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);
                        SocialFeedManager feedManager = new SocialFeedManager(clientContext);

                        // Publish the post. This is a root post to the user's feed, so specify
                        // null for the targetId parameter.
                        feedManager.CreatePost(null, postCreationData);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the first comment in following articles.
May be it helps..

http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2013/05/22/posting-on-sharepoint-2013-newsfeed-on-behalf-of-someone-else/

Comment: Please do not post link only answers! Add some details from the link to the post